# .remove() not working on a onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have two identical onClick functions in 2 different divs to save a dynamically generated string to a local variable. I'm having trouble clearing the local variable after it's been copied - which results in not being able to use the 2nd onClick function on the 2nd div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" onclick="copyThis('#link')">
  <span class="dynamicallyGeneratedText"></span>
</div>

<div class="container" onclick="copyThis('#link')">
  <span class="dynamicallyGeneratedText"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function copyThis(e) {
  var $link = $('<input>');
  $("body").append($link);
  $link.val($(e).text()).select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $link.remove();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `#link` an element within `document` ?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, yes it is

Comment: Then `js` at Question appears to return expected results ? Cannot reproduce _"having trouble clearing the local variable after it's been copied - which results in not being able to use the 2nd onClick function on the 2nd div"_

Comment: it works ONCE on the first div. when i try to use it again on the 2nd div, it gives me back the string that was copied from the first div. Hence why $link.remove() isn't working.

Comment: _"i try to use it again on the 2nd div, it gives me back the string that was copied from the first div"_ That is because you appear to be selecting the same text; that is, `$(e).text()` : `#link` element. Why would clipboard data change if same text is selected ?

Comment: Is requirement to select text of clicked element ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Since e.target seems to break my code, I can just create 2 similar but separate onClick functions for each div?

Comment: You should be able to use `js` at post. See https://jsfiddle.net/usewyx3m/ . Try clicking each element then pasting clipboard data after each click

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `e` to `event.target` at

```
function copyThis() {
  var $link = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($link);
  $link.val($(event.target).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $link.remove();
}
```

remove `#link` at

```
onclick="copyThis()"
```

Comment: @YNINNY Use `event.target`